# temporary private mounts

Tags: server, mount

I'm testing shared mounts on ubuntu server 14.04, and I'm having some issues regarding mount propagations.

```
#mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /mnt/tmp/
#mkdir /tmp/foo/
#mount -o bind /mnt/tmp/ /tmp/foo/
#mount -o remount,bind,private /tmp/foo/
#touch /tmp/foo/data
#ls -la /mnt/tmp/
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Aug  4 16:11 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Aug  4 16:13 data
# mount
/dev/mapper/ubucon--vg-root on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
/dev/vda1 on /boot type ext2 (rw)
rpc_pipefs on /run/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
tmpfs on /mnt/tmp type tmpfs (rw)
/mnt/tmp on /tmp/foo type none (rw,bind,private)
```

As you can see /tmp/foo is mounted as private, but filesystem propagation is still happening. Theorically when I create *data* in /tmp/foo/ it doesn't have to be listed on /mnt/tmp/. [Red Hat - Shared Mounts](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/sect-Using_the_mount_Command-Mounting-Bind.html)

Answer (score 2):

> Theorically when I create data in /tmp/foo/ it doesn't have to be listed on /mnt/tmp/.

False.

Private mounts do not propagate filesystem mount events. That is, if you mount something within an entry in a private mount, it won't be reflected in the original.

The four related types of mounts (shared, slave, private, unbindable) deal only with how mount events related to the mounts propagate.

Have a look at [the kernel documentation (in `Documentation/filesystems/sharedsubtree.txt`)](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/Documentation/filesystems/sharedsubtree.txt). The examples should make it clear.

Comment: You are right. I realized what i was doing wrong. Thanks for the input.